# Sox - Using silence effect in C++

Tags: c++, sox, libsox

I am trying to use the sox silence effect in C++

```
char* silenceOptions[25];
silenceOptions[0] = "-l 1 0.2 1% -1 0.2 1%";
sox_effect_options(effect, 7, silenceOptions);
```

I get the output:

```
silence: usage: [ -l ] above_periods [ duration threshold[d|%] ] [ below_periods duration threshold[d|%] ]
```

What is the correct way of passing the arguments to the silence effect?

```
int sox_effect_options(sox_effect_t *effp, int argc, char * const argv[]);
```

I am confused whether argc is a number of arguments of the size of argv?
What wrong with "-l 1 0.2 1% -1 0.2 1%"?

Comment: Do note that `silenceOptions[0] = "-l 1 0.2 1% -1 0.2 1%";` is illegal C++.  It is removing the const from the string literal.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I use gcc 7.4.0, I do get the warning, but that is the way [sox examples](https://github.com/chirlu/sox/blob/master/src/example0.c) do this so I tried a similar way.

Comment: Aha.  They are using C code, not C++.  Don't try to make C++ like C, they are different languages.

Comment: Right, missed that, but still, the problem remains.